# Fail to start Mongock CLI with Spring Boot, NullPointerException: Cannot invoke buildRunner

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongock

I've tried using Mongock for DB migrations and it's a really good tool. It activates when main application is launched. Recently I found out that there is Mongock CLI, and it suits better for my aims. Unfortunately, I fail to make it work. I took my previous project as template, `mvn clean package` it, jar file is successfully created in `target` folder. I follow instructions in [documentation](https://docs.mongock.io/v5/cli/index.html), but get an error.

Maybe I launch it incorrectly or I'm missing some code. That's what I do in console:
`cd D:\Programs\mongock-cli-5.0.26` (path to mongock cli) and
`./mongock migrate all -aj D:\Java Projects\mongock\target\cinema.jar` (path to intellij idea project, which contains the jar)

It generates this file:

```
#!/bin/sh
#Generated cli script
 java -jar mongock-cli-5.0.26.jar \
 --cli-spring-jar lib/mongock-cli-springboot-5.0.26.jar \
 --cli-core-jar lib/mongock-cli-core-5.0.26.jar \
 --mongock-core-jar lib/mongock-runner-core-5.1.0.jar \
 "$@"  \
  \
```

As I understand, I should copy it to console. I removed backslashes (it doesn't work if they stay), and that's the string I've got: `java -jar mongock-cli-5.0.26.jar --cli-spring-jar lib/mongock-cli-springboot-5.0.26.jar --cli-core-jar lib/mongock-cli-core-5.0.26.jar --mongock-core-jar lib/mongock-runner-core-5.1.0.jar` and I added `migrate all` to the end of this string.
I run it in console and get an error:

> i.m.cli.wrapper.launcher.LauncherDefault : launching Mongock CLI
> runner with default launcher java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot
> invoke
> "io.mongock.runner.core.builder.RunnerBuilder.buildRunner(io.mongock.runner.core.executor.operation.Operation)"
> because "this.builder" is null
> at io.mongock.cli.core.commands.migrate.MigrateCommand.all(MigrateCommand.java:38)

Do you have any ideas how to solve it? Should I include `@Bean RunnerBuilder`? It was't specified in docs, so I guess my mistake is in something else.

I also tried to run a bash file with that generated code (I'm using Windows): `bash script.sh`, but nothing happened. Cursor just moves to the next line and no changes applied in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems to happen because you are not passing the parameter -aj to provide your uber jar.

The command should be something like this:

```
java -jar mongock-cli-5.0.26.jar --cli-spring-jar lib/mongock-cli-springboot-5.0.26.jar --cli-core-jar lib/mongock-cli-core-5.0.26.jar --mongock-core-jar lib/mongock-runner-core-5.1.0.jar migrate all -aj D:\YOUR_JAR_PATH.jar
```

That should work.

Anyway, the Mongock team is providing a bat script that will do the same as the current `.sh` script for Linux. It's expected to be released at the end of the day. If not, in the next few days :)

Comment: Thank you very much dear Mongock team! It solved my issue. I'm grateful for such a quick response :)